# A cada UPDATE realizado do mesmo texto, a letra que possui acentuação é duplicada

Tags: php

A cada atualização do mesmo texto, os caracteres que possuem acentuação são duplicados.

Veja na imagem abaixo o que acontece a cada vez que clico em atualizar. Como se pode ver, as letras que possuem algum tipo de acentuação são duplicadas.

O faço para que os caracteres com acentuação não sejam mais duplicados?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Código Formulário:**

```
<?php
$painel=mysqli_query($con,"select detalhe_sobre from anuncios where id = '$idcli'");
while($painel_texto=mysqli_fetch_array($painel)){
$texto_empresa = utf8_encode(strip_tags(nl2br($painel_texto['detalhe_sobre'])));
}
?>
<form class="frm-adm-painel" action="gravar-texto.php?cliente=<?php echo $idcli; ?>" method="post">
    <textarea name="textoempresarial" rows="10" placeholder="Texto sobre a Empresa"><?php echo $texto_empresa;  ?></textarea>
    <button type="submit" name="botao">GRAVAR</button>
</form>
```

**Código gravar:**

```
<?php
if (!empty($_GET['cliente'])){
    $idcli = $_GET['cliente'];
    $textoempresarial = utf8_encode($_POST['textoempresarial']);
    $painel=mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE anuncios SET detalhe_sobre = '$textoempresarial' where id = '$idcli'");
    header("location: painel.php?cliente=$idcli");
}
?>
```

Comment: Os recuos são causador pq da quebra de linha dentro do `<textarea>`, sei q o objetivo era deixar o código mais legível, mas remova o resto tenho q olhar com calma

Comment: Sobre os caracteres especiais o que acontece se vc simplesmente usar `$texto_empresa = $painel_texto['detalhe_sobre'];` na hora de trazer os dados do banco?

Comment: @ErlonCharles Removi as quebras de linhas dentro do textarea e dei certo. Agora a sua segunda sugestão não dei certo, continua acrescentando caracteres especiais. Na verdade o que acontece é que se houver algum tipo a acentuação ou cedilha no texto ele duplicada a cada atualização.

Comment: @ErlonCharles Se no texto não houver caracteres com acentuação ele atualiza perfeitamente. O que torna quase impossível um texto sem acentuação. rss

Comment: Qual o formato do arquivo que está o form? está UTF-8?

Comment: @ErlonCharles como verifico essa informação?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62743/discussion-between-erlon-charles-and-gladison).